# What is the problem in my javascript code - delete an HTML element based on a condition (presence of another element) - beginner

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes, simple-html-dom

I am trying to delete an element when that element contains another element on https://medium.com/

Sorry, all the pictures are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp255.jpg - did not have the reputation to embed them :)

1. Medium homepage - without code. Nothing changes when I inject my .js code
2. If the < article class > contains this element, then the < article class > should be deleted
3. the < article class > that should be deleted if it contains the < span class > with a star SVG icon
4. Expected final result (I can't get this to work yet)

Can you please help me?

```
function removeElement(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var dad = elem.parentNode.parentNode.prentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    dad.removeChild(dad.firstChild);
}

function destroyLoop() {
    var i = O;
    while (i < 100) {
        removeElement("svgIcon svgIcon--star svgIcon--15px");
        i++;
    }
}



destroyLoop();
```

I expect the code to actually delete the element but nothing seems to happen

A million thanks

Comment: Your removeElement function expects an id, but you call it with a looong string (probably classes).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing class name as id here. Use this piece of code. This will get the first element of the class and delete it.

```
function removeElement(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[0].closest("article");
    var dad = elem.parentNode;
    dad.removeChild(elem);
}


function destroyLoop() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        removeElement("svgIcon svgIcon--star svgIcon--15px");
        i++;
    }
}



destroyLoop();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm a beginner but I see my mistake - you are right! But your code does not seem to work on my side. Did you test it or did you have any other ideas?

Comment: do you want to remove the <article> in which `svgIcon svgIcon--star svgIcon--15px` exists? If so, please check my answer again.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! That is very kind. https://imgur.com/a/AetIOcY - This is basically the sequence that I want the code to do.

Comment: This does not work yet - Any clue to what causes that?

Comment: This is what I get - Does anyone have any idea about what can be done? https://imgur.com/a/cIWNRll - Thanks again

Comment: you are assigning the character `O` in i. please assign numeric `0`. `var i = 0;`